# Отобрать из строки одну или несколько уникальных полседовательностей чисел

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
p_dbs varchar(1000):='MK~RU_AR~ZEN~ADFORM_CP~3301071970_CI~FY22QO_OB~1X1_TS~APV-123895_VV~NONE_PI~123895_ID~GLD0009ADF__CV~PPV-123895_FF~CPM';
type values_t is table of varchar(150);
    t_values     values_t := values_t();
    l_char                  varchar2(1 char);
    l_buffer                varchar2(150 char);
    l_sp    boolean :=false;
    l_ep    boolean :=false;
begin
    for i in 1..length(p_dbs)
    loop
        l_char := substr(p_dbs, i, 1);
        if nvl(length(replace(translate(l_char, '0123456789', rpad(chr(1), 10, chr(1))), chr(1))), 0) = 0 and l_sp=false  and l_ep=false
        then -- char is number
            l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
            l_sp := true;
            end if;
        
        if nvl(length(replace(translate(l_char, '0123456789', rpad(chr(1), 10, chr(1))), chr(1))), 0) = 0 and l_sp=true  and l_ep=false 
        then l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
        end if;
        
        if nvl(length(replace(translate(l_char, '0123456789', rpad(chr(1), 10, chr(1))), chr(1))), 0) > 0 and l_sp=true  and l_ep=false
        then 
             if --length(l_buffer)=5 or length(l_buffer)=6
              not l_buffer  MEMBER OF t_values then 
             t_values.EXTEND;
                 t_values(t_values.COUNT) := l_buffer;
                 dbms_output.put_line(l_buffer);
                 l_buffer := '';
                 l_sp := false;
                 l_ep := true;
           end if;
        end if;
        
        if nvl(length(replace(translate(l_char, '0123456789', rpad(chr(1), 10, chr(1))), chr(1))), 0) = 0 and l_sp=false  and l_ep=true 
        then 
            l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
            l_sp := true;
            l_ep := false;
        end if;
        end loop;
end;
```

Непонянтное поведение, показал значение которого нет 1123895:

```
33301071970
22
1
1123895
123895
0009
```

Если убрать проверку по member of , то показывает правильные данные:

```
33301071970
22
1
1
123895
123895
0009
123895
```

Если же проверять на колличество символов то результирующий набор пустой.

Как добиться такого результата, что бы в тип записалось только одно значение:

```
123895
```

Comment: Поясните что должны означать `l_sp` и `l_ep`

Comment: l_sp начало последовательности из чисел, l_ep  конец последовательности цифр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понял что должны означать флаги (`l_sp` и `l_ep`) в Вашем коде и поэтому не совсем понял как его исправить.

Можно построить запрос на основе регулярных выражений.

Вот такой запрос например вытаскивает из строки числовые последовательности:

```
select regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) 
  from dual
connect by regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Как он работает: функция [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) возвращает N-ю последовательность в строке, которая соответствует регулярному выражению. Регулярное выражение `[[:digit:]]+` вытаскивает последовательности чисел. Рекурсивный запрос (`connect by`) будет вытаскивать все последовательности чисел по очереди пока они не закончатся (вернется пустая строка, т.е. `null`).

Теперь можно вытащить из строки уникальные последовательности нужной длины:

```
select t.numbers
  from (select regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) as numbers,
               level as l --Номер последовательности с начала строки
          from dual
        connect by regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) is not null) t
 where length(t.numbers) in (5, 6) --фильтр по длине
 group by t.numbers
 order by min(t.l) --Сортируем последовательности в оригинальном порядке (если это нужно) 
                   -- Если сортировка не нужна, то можно обойтись DISTINCT
                   -- (убрать GROUP BY и поле L из вложенного запроса)
```

Можно их вывести:

```
  for r in (select t.numbers
              from (select regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) as numbers,
                           level as l
                      from dual
                    connect by regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) is not null) t
             where length(t.numbers) in (5, 6)
             group by t.numbers
             order by min(t.l)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.numbers);
  end loop;
```

Можно собрать в коллекцию:

```
select t.numbers bulk collect
  into t_values
  from (select regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) as numbers,
               level as l
          from dual
        connect by regexp_substr(p_dbs, '[[:digit:]]+', 1, level) is not null) t
 where length(t.numbers) in (5, 6)
 group by t.numbers
 order by min(t.l);
```

### Дополнение по оригинальному коду

> Я тестировал с ипользованиям конструкции from dual connect by regexp_substr, очень долго работает по сравнению с текущей версией.
> l_sp начало последовательности из чисел, l_ep конец последовательности цифр

Попробовал упростить оригинальный код. Вроде бы можно обойтись без флагов. Попробуйте такой пример:

```
declare
  p_dbs varchar(1000) := 'MK~RU_AR~ZEN~ADFORM_CP~3301071970_CI~FY22QO_OB~1X1_TS~APV-123895_VV~NONE_PI~123895_ID~GLD0009ADF__CV~PPV-123895_FF~CPM';
  type values_t is table of varchar(150);
  t_values values_t := values_t();
  l_char   varchar2(1 char);
  l_buffer varchar2(150 char);
begin
  for i in 1 .. length(p_dbs) loop
    l_char := substr(p_dbs, i, 1);
    --Проверка на цифру
    if length(trim(translate(l_char, '01234576789', ' '))) is null then
      -- Если цифра, добавляем ее в последовательность
      l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
    elsif l_buffer is not null then
      --Если не цифра, то проверяем есть ли последовательность
      --Выполняем все нужные проверки
      if length(l_buffer) in (5, 6) and not l_buffer MEMBER OF t_values then
        t_values.EXTEND;
        t_values(t_values.COUNT) := l_buffer;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_buffer);
      end if;
      l_buffer := '';
    end if;
  
  end loop;
  --Проверка на случай если числовая последовательность в самом конце строки
  if l_buffer is not null then
    if (length(l_buffer) = 5 or length(l_buffer) = 6) and not l_buffer
     MEMBER OF t_values then
      t_values.EXTEND;
      t_values(t_values.COUNT) := l_buffer;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_buffer);
    end if;
    l_buffer := '';
  end if;
end;
```

Соответственно, функция может выглядеть вот так:

```
create or replace function get_distinct_dbs_2(p_dbs in varchar2)
  return varchar2 deterministic as

  type values_t is table of varchar(150);
  t_values values_t := values_t();
  l_ret    varchar2(4000 char);
  l_char   varchar2(1 char);
  l_buffer varchar2(35 char);
begin
  for i in 1 .. length(p_dbs) loop
    l_char := substr(p_dbs, i, 1);
    --Проверка на цифру
    if length(trim(translate(l_char, '01234576789', ' '))) is null then
      -- Если цифра, добавляем ее в последовательность
      l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
    elsif l_buffer is not null then
      --Если не цифра, то проверяем есть ли последовательность
      --Выполняем все нужные проверки
      if length(l_buffer) in (5, 6) and not l_buffer MEMBER OF t_values then
        t_values.EXTEND;
        t_values(t_values.COUNT) := l_buffer;
        l_ret := l_ret || ';' || l_buffer;
      end if;
      l_buffer := '';
    end if;
  
  end loop;
  --Проверка на случай если числовая последовательность в самом конце строки
  if length(l_buffer) in (5, 6) and not l_buffer MEMBER OF t_values then
    l_ret := l_ret || ';' || l_buffer;
  end if;

  l_ret := ltrim(l_ret, ';');
  return l_ret;
end;
```

В Вашем коде судя по всему ошибка в двух взаимовлияющих условиях:

```
--Добавили цифру, начали последовательность.
if l_test=TRUE and l_sp=false  and l_ep=false then
    l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
    l_sp := true;
end if;
--Если последовательность начата, то добавляем цифру еще раз
if l_test=TRUE and l_sp=true  and l_ep=false then 
    l_buffer := l_buffer || l_char;
end if;
```

Из-за этого функция будет добавлять первый символ последовательности дважды, что приведет к ошибкам. Например, для входящей строки `1235a` вернется значение `11235`.

Comment: добрый день. Благодарю за ответ. Я тестировал с ипользованиям конструкции   from dual connect by regexp_substr, очень долго работает по сравнению с текущей версией.

Comment: @ default locale решил проблему уникальности записей, записав значения в индекс коллекции

Comment: @максимильин Попробовал упростить Ваш код, посмотрите дополнение в ответе

Comment: @ default locale Огромное вам спасибо.. Дублирующие условие с символом, и если последовательность была в конце то не находил.